# Python - How to calculate this recursive function time complexity?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I wanted to solve the tower hopper problem in as much ways that I can and calculate each way's time complexity (just for self practice).
One of the solution is this:

```
def is_hopable(arr):
    if len(arr) < 1 or arr[0] == 0:
        return False
    if arr[0] >= len(arr):
        return True
    res = False
    for i in range(1,arr[0]+1):
        res = res or is_hopable(arr[i:]) # This line  
    return res
```

I know the general idea of recursive time complexity calculation but I'm having trouble to analyze the commented line (inside the for loop). Usually I calculate the time complexity with `T(n) = C + T(that line)` and reduce it with a general expression (for example T(n-k)) until I reach the base case and can express k with n, but what is the time complexity of that for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity of that `for` loop could be up to `O(n^2)` because every iteration of the loop (up to n iterations) do a slice `arr[i:]` that return a copy of `arr` without first `i` elements `O(n)`. With that in mind overall time is `O(n^3)`.

Mentioned upper bound is tight.
Example: `arr = [n-1, n-2, n-3, ..., 1, 1]`
Alternative form: `arr[i] = n - 1 - i` for all `i`, `0 <= i < n - 1`, and `arr[n-1] = 1` where `n` is length of `arr`.

The recurrence to calculate amount of elemental operations (avoiding the use of constant) can be stated as:
[image: 1]

Simplify summation:
[image: 2]

Evaluate (unroll) lesser terms of T and search a lower bound:
[image: 3]

Use [formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/) of sum of squares from `1` to `n`:
[image: 5]

As T(n) lower bound is a polynomial of degree 3 we have found that such instance of the problem running time is `Ω(n^3)` proving that the upper bound for the problem (`O(n^3)`) is tight.

Side note:
If you use as parameters original array and current index the runtime of `for` loop will be `O(n)` and overall time `O(n^2)`.